# Dependency Injection Container for each Class Library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, unity-container

So, this is the first time I'm dealing with DI, please correct me if I misunderstood the whole DI thingy.

These are few of my projects:

1. Web Application/ Web API Project - Depends on Service Class + inject Automapper (Configuration only applicable for current project)
2. Service (Class Library) - Depends on Data Class + inject Automapper (Configuration only applicable for current project)
3. Data (Class Library)

My intention was to have each project having its own DI container (says Unity DI). I'm not sure that each project can have its own DI container.

I have read some of the article, showing that it cannot be done (not sure if i interpret them correctly) but I'm not sure why?

If it **cannot** be done, can anyone explain it and how can I achieve this and I doesn't want to register the classes in Data Layer in the Application Layer DI.

If each project **can** have its own DI, when registering the IMapper as instance will it override IMapper of other layers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My intention was to have each project having its own DI container (says Unity DI). I'm not sure that each project can have its own DI container.

As explained [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), you should compose all object graphs:

> **As close as possible to the application's entry point.**

This place is called the **Composition Root**:

> **A Composition Root is a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together.**

In other words, the only place that you should use your DI container and configure your application's dependencies is in the start-up project. All other projects should be oblivious to the container and should purely apply **Constructor Injection**.

> I have read some of the article, showing that it cannot be done

It can be done, but you shouldn't.

> If each project can have its own DI, when registering the IMapper as instance will it override IMapper of other layers?

This problem goes away if you apply the **Composition Root** pattern. In the **Composition Root** you have full control over which component gets which dependency.

**PRO TIP**: Read [this book](https://manning.com/seemann/).

Comment: Does this mean for every consumer of service.dll will need to have composite root to include the dependencies? What if i need to release this dll to public?

Comment: @Leonz: If you create reusable libraries, [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/) and [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/) advice applies.

Comment: "Does this mean for every consumer of service.dll will need to have composite root to include the dependencies?" Only the start-up project will have a Composite Root and typically, Composition Roots are [not reused](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/).